# EF Core properties by SQL statement

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm currently refactoring a codebase which uses a self designed ORM to use EF core as it's ORM.
The current ORM has a "feature" which makes is possible to define a property on a model object by a SQL statement.
Here is an example of that feature:

```
[MapDb(PropBySql = "select count(clqh.id) from tbl_checklist_question_history clqh where clqh.ChecklistHistory_id = o.id and Answer = 0")]
public int UnAnsweredQuestions { get; set; }
```

If I get the value of this property while running the code I would get the result of the SQL query.

I was wondering if EF core has something like this? If not what would be the best way to refactor these properties?

Comment: Shouldn't it be read only (only `get` method, no `set`) since you can't insert a value from this query?

Comment: The ORM makes use of reflection to check if there are properties on a model object that have a SQL statement. If so, the result of the query is read using ADO.NET and set.
But I don't fully understand why the configuration of the property is important regarding the question asked.